# List HDFS files bigger than specific file size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I list HDFS files bigger than a specific file size? Is there any command in hadoop or hadoop + some linux command?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds easy to be achieved by java API, using `FileStatus[] listStatus(Path f)` to get a array of `FileStatus` and then filter file by size.

Comment: i'm looking something to write in bash. At this moment, using `files= hadoop fs -ls /tmp/*.csv | awk '{print $3, $6}'` and looping through the files to look for specific size and filename.